# Can someone explain how this MongoClient.connect code work?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

Can someone please explain the concept here. I've put three console.log in the code in order to find out how this code is running. However, I don't understand why contestCount++ is being called four times before it moves on to client 2. (By the way, there are four documents in the contests collection) I expect the code goes all the way from top to bottom then loops back to the top again. Thank you

```
MongoClient.connect(
  config.mongodbUri,
  { useUnifiedTopology: true },
  (err, client) => {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    let contestCount = 0;
    /* client 1 */
    client  
      .db('test')
      .collection('contests')
      .find({})
      .each((err, contest) => {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        if (!contest) {
          return;
        }

        contestCount++;
        /* console.log */
        console.log(`contestCountPlus: ${contestCount}`);

        /* client 2 */
        client
          .db('test')
          .collection('names')
          .find({ id: { $in: contest.nameIds } })
          .project({ _id: 1 })
          .toArray()
          .then((_ids) => {
            const newIds = _ids.map((o) => o._id);

            /* client 3 */
            client
              .db('test')
              .collection('contests')
              .updateOne({ id: contest.id }, { $set: { nameIds: newIds } })
              .then(() => {
                contestCount--;
                /* console.log */
                console.log(`contestCountMinus: ${contestCount}`);
                if (contestCount === 0) {
                  /* console.log */
                  console.log(`contestCountFinal: ${contestCount}`);
                  client.close();
                }
              });
          })
          .catch(console.error);
      });
  }
);
```

Here's what I get from the terminal

```
Stevens-MBP:learn-fullstack-javascript stevenlai$ babel-node updateTestData.js
contestCountPlus: 1
contestCountPlus: 2
contestCountPlus: 3
contestCountPlus: 4
contestCountMinus: 3
contestCountMinus: 2
contestCountMinus: 1
contestCountMinus: 0
contestCountFinal: 0
```

Comment: How many documents are there in the collection 'contests'?

Comment: @prasad_ There are 4 documents

Comment: You are using multiple collections in your code. You may want to post a sample document of each collection in your question.

Comment: Also see this: [What are callbacks?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/)

Answer (score 0):

All of the client operations are asynchronous. In your code you are initiating the decrements when you are processing each of the documents in the outer loop, but this isn't the order in which decrements are actually executed. In your case first all documents in the outer loop are processed and the decrements are "queued", then each of the decrements gets processed.

This is in general how node works, nothing here is mongodb-specific.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much for your help!